# Domain issue on $\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

$$\int\arctan\left( \frac 1 x \right)\,dx$$

I used this method:

### Method 1

$u=\arctan(\frac{1}{x})$ and $du=-\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx$

$dv=dx$ and $v=x$

Then I get:

$$x\tan^{-1} \left(\frac 1 x \right) + \int\frac{x}{1+x^2} \, dx$$

$$x\tan^{-1} \left(\frac 1 x \right)+\frac 1 2 \int\frac 1 u \, du$$

$$x\tan^{-1} \left(\frac 1 x \right) +\frac{\ln(1+x^2)} 2 + C$$

While integrating I realized that the function $\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x})$ does
not serve as a cofunction for $\cot^{-1}(x)$, and it only does so for part of the domain.

### My Question

Is there a cofunction using $\tan^{-1}$ that fits $\cot^{-1}$ domain completely?

Comment: What do you mean by a cofunction? If you mean that $\arctan \dfrac 1 x$ is not the same as $\operatorname{arccot} x,$ then certainly it is true that they coincide when $x>0$ and they differ by a constant when $x<0.$ And in this case in the expression $\text{“} \cdots +C\text{''}$ the $\text{“}C\text{''}$ must be views as a piecewise constant, which need not have the same value on the positive half of the axis as on the negative half.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because of the following reasons:

First; $\tan^{-1}$ and $\cot^{-1}$ does not take angles as inputs, they take ratios between right-triangle sides as inputs.

Second; they have different codomains and ranges
$$ \tan^{-1} : \mathbb{R} \to \left] -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right[ $$
$$ \cot^{-1} : \mathbb{R} \to \left] 0, \pi \right[ $$

So $\tan^{-1}$ never attains values in $ \left [ \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi \right[ $.

Third; consider the cofuntions identity equation
$$ \tan^{-1}(\frac{\pi}{2} - x) = \cot^{-1}(x) $$

then by derivating both sides
$$ \frac{2 \pi }{\pi ^2 x^2+4}=-\frac{1}{x^2+1} $$
$$ x = \pm i \sqrt{\frac{4+2 \pi }{2 \pi +\pi ^2}} $$

That is, there exists only two points satisfying the cofuntions identity equation and they will be purely imaginary.

Actually, cofunctions inverses satisfy an analagous identity to
$$ \tan(\frac{\pi}{2} - x) = \cot(x) $$

Namely,
$$ \frac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1}(x) = \cot^{-1}(x) $$